# Problem with the implementation of the Android Studio Java design libraries

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having a problem with this library: 
`com.android.support:design:25.0.1`

When I go to implement it using: `implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'`  an error appears

```
or:Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward.
```

the strange thing is that when I go to syncronize and when I try to put in the `xml: <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton />` the piece of code turns red and if I go over it with the mouse it appears:

```
Cannot resolve class android. support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.
```

All of this happens even if I try to put version `29.0.0` of `implementation com.android.support:design` or if I try to put version 28.0.0.

image link:

[image]

[image]

Comment: First, Migrate to `androidX` by right click -> Refactor -> Migrate to `androidX` in `build.gradle` file, then replace the Floating button line with `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton`. You can read more about it [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/floating-action-button/).

Comment: Also, you should not provide images instead of code. You can read why not [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Also, version `29.0.0` of the android.support libraries doesn't exist.  Last version was 28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version
>   of the support library called AndroidX which is part of Jetpack.

You should use `androidx` instead of `android.support` libraries in your project. Using `android.support` libraries will prevent you from using latest `play services` and `jetpack` features.

You can refactor your project to use the `androidx` libraries instead by **Refactor -> Migrate to androidX**

Migarting your project to androidx should change your dependency `com.android.support:design:25.0.1` to `'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`